# Magento 2.1.6 minicart not updating and Checkout page always empty

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.1.6

Please I need some help with my magento 2.1.6 store. My AJAX minicart does not update when I add a product to the cart but the product actually reflects when I go directly to the cart page. When I click on the AJAX minicart, it produces a blank little box with nothing inside it.
My checkout page also gives me a blank page when I load it and am unable to checkout successfully. My website is https://www.jibosky.com Please help me check it and confirm what I am talking about. My full page cache is active and I have magento caching enabled for my store. I don't get any error relating to this on my browser console and log folder. I run EM Necessary theme based on Luma

I received the following errors on my browser console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'mage-cache-storage' exceeded the quota.
at Object.r (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/jquery/jquery.storageapi.min.js:1:1357)
at Object._callMethod (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/jquery/jquery.storageapi.min.js:1:4103)
at Object.set (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/jquery/jquery.storageapi.min.js:1:4445)
at eval (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.min.js:3:269)
at Function._.each._.forEach (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/underscore.min.js:7:650)
at Object.update (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.min.js:3:142)
at Object.eval (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.min.js:8:324)
at fire (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/jquery.min.js:188:299)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/jquery.min.js:193:198)
at done (https://www.jibosky.com/static/version1501500835/frontend/Emthemes/necessary_default/en_US/jquery.min.js:586:95)
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
Message: cart is not a function
at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.min.js:NaN), <anonymous>:3:71)
at update (knockout.min.js:349)
at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.min.js:297)
at evaluateImmediate (knockout.min.js:178)
at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.min.js:199)
at eval (knockout.min.js:297)
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.min.js:12)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.min.js:294)
at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.min.js:283)
at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.min.js:280)
css @ VM3424:3
update @ knockout.min.js:349
ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved @ knockout.min.js:297
evaluateImmediate @ knockout.min.js:178
ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable @ knockout.min.js:199
(anonymous) @ knockout.min.js:297
arrayForEach @ knockout.min.js:12
applyBindingsToNodeInternal @ knockout.min.js:294
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.min.js:283
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.min.js:280
ko.applyBindingsToDescendants @ knockout.min.js:303
applyComponents @ scope.min.js:1
_resolveRequest @ registry.min.js:16
_updateRequests @ registry.min.js:16
later @ underscore.min.js:41
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Clear cache and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from CLI and refresh page and try.

Comment: @AmanAlam I have done that severally but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

please try below steps to resolve the minicart issue -

1. Replace the minicart.phtml file from theme (*app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t*) with core template (*vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌*​).
2. Replace content.html file from your theme (*app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html*) with core template (*vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html*)
3. Remove all pub/static/frontend , remove var folder. Run deploy static content again : **php magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: I've also tried this method step by step but it did not work out